# Unable to identify solution to compiler error using Boost Units

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

**Boost Units version**: 1.45

**Compiler**: Visual Studio 2008

**Platform**: Windows 7

**Error**: When compiling the following code I get an error C2440 "initializing' : cannot convert from 'boost::units::quantity' to 'boost::units::quantity' with

`[
Unit=boost::units::unit>,boost::units::detail::static_power_impl<0>::apply>::type,boost::units::hogogeneous_system>>>>,
Y = double
]`

and

`[
Unit=myproject::types::myproject_length
]`

Constructor for class 'boost::units::quantity' is declared 'explicit' with

`[
Unit=myproject::types::myproject_length
]`

I am not sure what is wrong here. If I remove the "radii_t result =" from the following code and comment out the IO statement I get the same error as previously quoted above.
Below is the code I used. I appreciate your patience as I learn Boost
Units.

Q1: What is the reason for this error? What in the error output helped
you to figure that out.

Q2: Even if the above error did not exist you mentioned that it would
fail the dimensional analysis. I think we both agree the type would be
radii^-1. How do you declare a type to be raised to the correct power?

Stephen

```
#include <boost/units/base_unit.hpp>
#include <boost/units/base_units/angle/radian.hpp>
#include <boost/units/io.hpp>
#include <boost/units/make_system.hpp>
#include <boost/units/physical_dimensions/length.hpp>
#include <boost/units/physical_dimensions/time.hpp>
#include <boost/units/static_constant.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace myproject {
 namespace types {

   //-------------------------------------
   //          Base dimensions
   //-------------------------------------
   struct length_base_dimension : public boost::units::base_dimension<length_base_dimension,1> {};

   //-------------------------------------
   //          Dimensions
   //-------------------------------------

   struct radii_base_unit : public boost::units::base_unit<radii_base_unit, boost::units::length_dimension, 1>
   {
     static std::string name()   { return("radii"); }
     static std::string symbol() { return("r"); }
   };

   struct minute_base_unit : public boost::units::base_unit<minute_base_unit,boost::units::time_dimension,3>
   {
     static std::string name() { return ("minute"); }
     static std::string symbol() { return ("min"); }
   };

typedef boost::units::make_system<radii_base_unit,
                                 minute_base_unit,
                                 boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit >::type myproject_system_t;

   typedef boost::units::unit<boost::units::length_dimension,myproject_system_t> myproject_length;

   typedef boost::units::quantity<myproject_length, double> radii_t;

   BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(radii,myproject_length);
 }
}

int main ( int, char** )
{
 using namespace myproject::types;

 radii_t val1 ( 5 * radii );
 radii_t val2 ( 3 * radii );

 radii_t result =  1.0 / ( val1 - val2 );

 std::cout << result << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The core problem is that your compiler message is truncated. In gcc, it reads:

`54:40: error: conversion from ‘boost::units::divide_typeof_helper<double, boost::units::quantity<boost::units::unit<boost::units::list<boost::units::dim<boost::units::length_base_dimension, boost::units::static_rational<1l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::homogeneous_system<boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit, boost::units::list<myproject::types::radii_base_unit, boost::units::list<myproject::types::minute_base_unit, boost::units::dimensionless_type> > > > >, double> >::type {aka boost::units::quantity<boost::units::unit<boost::units::list<boost::units::dim<boost::units::length_base_dimension, boost::units::static_rational<-0x00000000000000001l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::homogeneous_system<boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit, boost::units::list<myproject::types::radii_base_unit, boost::units::list<myproject::types::minute_base_unit, boost::units::dimensionless_type> > > >, void>, double>}’ to non-scalar type ‘myproject::types::radii_t {aka boost::units::quantity<boost::units::unit<boost::units::list<boost::units::dim<boost::units::length_base_dimension, boost::units::static_rational<1l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::homogeneous_system<boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit, boost::units::list<myproject::types::radii_base_unit, boost::units::list<myproject::types::minute_base_unit, boost::units::dimensionless_type> > > > >, double>}’ requested`

However, in general boost-units compiler errors are a little ... verbose. Normally, I don't try to understand them, but rather use boost.units to verify that my units are correct, and if they aren't, have a long hard look at the code to determine what's wrong. In your case, you could compare the `aka` types and see that the signs for the length base dimensions differ.

For Q2, `boost::units::power_typeof_helper` is your friend, as well as the other type helpers.